# How I can configure as router

Tags: networking, router, bridge, openwrt

I bought AR9331 which installed [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/)  (GL-iNet 6408A)
[image: AR9331]

Also, there is WiFi(wlan0), and two ethernet port [eth0, eth1].
One ethernet port is configured as WAN (eth0).

Also, there is bridge with `wlan0`, and `eth1`.
The bridge ip is 192.168.1.1

Also, I can connect with my laptop via wifi, and I can access openwrt luci with 192.168.1.1.

But, with ethernet cable(laptop eth0 <-> AR9331 eth1), I cannot connect to AR9331.

I want connect my laptop with ethernet ( eth1 ).
How I can connect with ethernet cable via 192.168.1.1?

Comment: What's the device model?

Comment: My device model is GL-iNet 6408A

Comment: It should be giving an IP out on eth0. Also, you are supposed to update the firmware before you deploy it. https://dl.gl-inet.com/firmware/mt300n-v2/v1/